# How to sort ArrayList<myobject> on the basis of myobject's properties

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

I want to sort some objects which are in an ArrayList on the basis of the objects properties.
the object has:

```
public class Minterm

{
    String minTerm;
    char flagTick;
    String minTermDerive;
    int groupNo;
    String adjGroup;
    static int MaxLiterals;
```

then i have this in the main method:

```
ArrayList<Minterm> column =new  ArrayList<Minterm>();
```

then i add some objects of type `Minterm` in the list. but at the end i want to organise them and sort them on the member variable `groupNo`(Ascending order).

i searched and came up with the comparable and comparator interfaces that i tried but didnt succeed. is there any other method to do this? or am i doing the comparator implemnting wrong.

**EDIT :**
Following is the code i wrote for Comparator. Please confirm if it will sort in ascending?

```
package backEnd;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class Comp implements Comparator<Minterm>
{
        @Override
        public int compare(Minterm a, Minterm b) 
        {
            return a.getgroupOne().compareTo(b.getgroupOne());
        }
}
```

i run it as:

```
Collections.sort(column , new Comp());
```

seems to be working fine. but i dont have a sound understanding of it.
Please confirm if it will sort in ascending?

Comment: Yes, you're probably doing it wrong. Show us the code, and we'll tell you where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should let `Minterm` implement `Comparable<MinTerm>` or write a custom `Comparator` for `MinTerm` and then use `Collections.sort`.

Using a comparator it would look like this:

```
Collections.sort(column, new Comparator<Minterm>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Minterm o1, Minterm o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(o1.groupNo).compareTo(o2.groupNo);
    }
});
```

**Regarding your edit:**

Yes. that sorts `Minterm`s based on the groups in *ascending* order.

Comment: You should prefer `Integer.valueOf()` to `new Integer()`, as it caches common values.

Comment: @JBNizet Well, technically it caches values between -128 and +127, rather than "common" values, although these are the most common *generally* speaking

Comment: @Bohemian: yes, that's what I meant with "common".

Comment: You can just use `Integer.compare(int, int)` directly as of Java 7 instead of going via the `Integer` boxing.

Answer (score 3):

[`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and the [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface are precisely the right tool for this job.

Something along the following lines should do it (untested):

```
  Collections.sort(column, new Comparator<Minterm>() {
     public int compare(Minterm o1, Minterm o2) {
       return Integer.valueOf(o1.groupNo).compareTo(o2.groupNo);
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways, using `Collections.sort(..)`:

- make your object implement `Comparable`. Involves changing the original class, which may not be possible
- supply custom `Comparator`. It takes instances of your object and compares them. Doesn't require a change to the class.

Either way, make sure you conform to the interfaces' contracts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code (for more examples refer http://java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/arraylist/sort-comparator/ ):

```
public class MyArrayListSort {

    public static void main(String a[]){

        List<Empl> list = new ArrayList<Empl>();
        list.add(new Empl("Ram",3000));
        list.add(new Empl("John",6000));
        list.add(new Empl("Crish",2000));
        list.add(new Empl("Tom",2400));
        Collections.sort(list,new MySalaryComp());
        System.out.println("Sorted list entries: ");
        for(Empl e:list){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

class MySalaryComp implements Comparator<Empl> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        if(e1.getSalary() < e2.getSalary()){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

class Empl{

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Empl(String n, int s){
        this.name = n;
        this.salary = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: "+this.name+"-- Salary: "+this.salary;
    }
}
```